# Jasmine spec failure for Angular CDK modal dialog

Tags: angular

I'm creating Jasmine specs for my CanDeactivate Guard (which uses a service to launch an Angular CDK Overlay). Here's the spec file:

```
class MockGuardComponent implements ComponentCanDeactivate {
  // Set this value to the value you want to mock being returned from 
GuardedComponent
  returnValue: boolean | Observable<boolean>;

  canDeactivate(): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    return this.returnValue;
  }
}

describe('PendingChangesGuard', () => {
  let mockGuardComponent: MockGuardComponent;
  let service: PendingChangesGuard;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [PendingChangesGuard, MockGuardComponent, Overlay],
    });
    service = TestBed.get(PendingChangesGuard);
    mockGuardComponent = TestBed.get(MockGuardComponent);
  });

  it('should expect service to instantiate', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('can route if unguarded -- form is not dirty', () => {
    mockGuardComponent.returnValue = true;
    expect(service.canDeactivate(mockGuardComponent)).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('will open the confirm dialog', () => {
    mockGuardComponent.returnValue = false;
    expect(service.canDeactivate(mockGuardComponent)).toBeFalsy();
    expect(service.openConfirmDialog).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

This is the *PendingChangesGuard* file:

```
export class PendingChangesGuard
  implements CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate> {
  constructor(private modalDialogService: ModalDialogService) {}

  canDeactivate(
    component: ComponentCanDeactivate
  ): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    return component.canDeactivate() || this.openConfirmDialog();
  }

  openConfirmDialog() {
    const ref = this.modalDialogService.open(ModalDialogComponent, null);
    return ref.afterClosed$();
  }
}
```

The Guard is working perfectly. The problem is that when I run the tests I get this error:

```
✗ will open the confirm dialog
    Error: No component factory found for ModalDialogComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

And I've definitely added it to the *entryComponents* of the *Core* module, not *AppModule*. Why is the test triggering this error?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else runs across this, you have to override the module in the spec file like this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    PendingChangesGuard,
    MockGuardComponent,
    Overlay,
  ],
}).overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
  set: {
    entryComponents: [ModalDialogComponent],
  },
});
```